# .NET framework : Are all System.* dlls not intellectual property?

Tags: .net, code-security

All .NET dlls can be reverse engineered easily, hence .NET can be considered as an intellectual property as opposed to C++. Recently I found that using some tool, all System.* dlls used in .NET project can also be peeped into. 
Question here is why System.* dlls in .NET are not obfuscated? What security is provided in .NET framework to make it more like intellectual property?

Answer (score 1):

There is no safety in obfuscating something that is open source and the code itself is publicly available online.

.NET Core is an open source project (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet)
The implementation for the individual classes that make up the full .NET Framework are also available at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Babak. Is plain .NET (not .NET Core) open source? If you have any useful link, please share.

Comment: I don't believe that the full .NET Framework is open source but this is a good place to start your investigations. https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet